# Build Date object with a date and a time

Tags: android, date, time

I receive two Strings, one with a date (say, "15-05-13") and with a time (say, "10:00").

What I need to achieve is make a Date object with both Strings, so I can check if the now Date is < 15 minutes than the Date formed with both Strings. How can I put together both Strings in the same Date object? Simply concatenating both Strings? I haven't tried, but I bet its not so simple...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, **c1** contains both dates.

```
Date date1 = ; // parse date "15-05-13"
Date date2 = ; // parse date "10:00"

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance().setTime(date1);
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance().setTime(date2);

c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, c2.get(Calendar.HOUR));
c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Answer (score 2):

After parsing each date / time, get just the milliseconds since epoch and compare

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YY");
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    long dateTime = date.parse("15-05-13").getTime() + time.parse("10:00").getTime();
    long mins = 15 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
    if(Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - dateTime) < mins) {
        //yup
    }
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The Math.abs is to see if the target date is within 15 mins of now (past and future) rather than only 15 mins in the past, or switch to dateTime - System.currentTimeMillis() for 15 mins in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23);
Date date = c.getTime();
```

and go on with the hours. The default `calendar` you get is initialized with `now`